Por que mi contador no funciona bien?
Quisiera saber el por que mi contador de interacciones(o repetidor) no funciona bien, dado a que le puesto un limite pero cuando llega a ese limite sigue ejecutándose y haciendo que me imprima el valor del repetidor me da siempre un valor de 0.
Aquí el código por si quieren verlo:
for(r=0;r<=10;r++)
{
    scanf("%s",&p);
    printf(" %c=%i \n",p,p);
    printf("\t %i \n",r);
}


Tu código se ejecuta hasta que "r" sea igual a 11, si quieres que se ejecute hasta el 10 debes quitar el operador "<=" (menor o igual que) y colocar solo "<" (menor que): for (int r=0;r<10;r++); . O simplemente cambiar el 10 por 9, ¿Te funcionó?.

El primer p de la función printf debe tener * para indicar que queremos leer un caracter(%c) y recomiendo usar %p para ver la dirección de memoria donde se guarda el texto: printf("El caracter \"%c\" esta en la dirección %p de memoria.\n",*p,p);
